# WebDriver ImplicitWait don't work, waiting for element is longer then setted

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using GhostDriver (PhantomJsDriver). It's implicit wait set to **2 seconds**: `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`

When trying to find an element in the DOM that doesn't exist (as expected), WebDriver trying polling the element for much longer time:

```
[ERROR - 2015-05-06T12:15:25.137Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1430914525093
[ERROR - 2015-05-06T12:15:27.716Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1430914527641
[ERROR - 2015-05-06T12:15:30.579Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - 
...
[ERROR - 2015-05-06T12:17:47.598Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1430914667555
[ERROR - 2015-05-06T12:17:50.481Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1430914670467
```

The first time equal to: 12:15:25, the last time equal to: 12:17:50 (using [epoch](http://www.epochconverter.com/) convertor).

It's about **~2 minutes** of timeout, when the implicit wait set to 2 seconds.

In [PhantomJs code](https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/source/browse/src/ghostdriver/webelementlocator.js?name=master) (which is the backend for GhostDriver), the wait looks pretty simple:

```
 if (elementOrElements) {

        _log.error("_handleLocateCommand", "Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: " + stopSearchByTime);

        _errors.handleFailedCommandEH(elementOrElements.status,
            elementOrElements.value.message,
            req,
            res,
            _session);
        return;
    }
```

But in this case doesn't take into account at all the implicit waiting time. So, how this wait time controlled?
What could be the cause for the ultra-long wait time?

Comment: Are you using explicit wait with that?

Comment: @Saifur - Yes, it's in the code but not appear in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit and Explicit waits are thoroughly tested and used by good number of users. As you mentioned that you are using explicit wait with Implicit that's clearly indicated the reason of that unexpected behavior. I did a good amount of research on how mixing them up together can adversely change the timeout. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474296/clarification-on-the-cause-of-mixing-implicit-and-explicit-waits-in-selenium-doc). And, I would suggest you to remove the explicit or any other kind of wait and retest.

Comment: Thanks, the link you attached contains the exact reason for the issue I have experienced.