# To Pick the First Airport Code from the Auto-populated list in Selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have to automate the Flight page for the below URL

URL: https://www.cheapoair.com/deals/business-class-airfares

Enter LAS in the 'Flying From ' Textbox and you will see the list getting displayed and have to select the First Airport code from the auto-populated list matching the Airport Code .

I have to automate using Selenium with java. Could you share the piece of code for it.

[Flight image with Autopopulated origin List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxEHr.png)

Comment: I have already implemented mine code in the project . But it was not 100% efficient. I used to pick the origin or destination from Excel sheet and populate in sheet. Then once the list is autopopulated , I wait for the close button which is at bottom. Then I click on close button. This is process I used for similar scenario in my project. I have already lot of research and project is running for last 6 month

Comment: Great, then post the code that isn't working... it's not clear what your actual question is and you haven't met the basic guidelines for a question with the limited info you've provided.

Comment: Please share your work

Comment: @iamsankalp89 - URL: cheapoair.com/deals/business-class-airfares . if u eneter the origin as 'LAS', the list is autopopulated , but u cannot inspect element to select the xpath for the Autopopulated list. Currently Close icon appears in the bottom and i click on that and las get populated. But I have to select the Aiirport code from the List.

Answer (score 1):

Given this select:

```
<select name="airports" id="airport"> 
<option value="lax">Los Angeles</option >
<option value="sfo">San Francisco</option >
<option value="pdx">Portland</option >
</select>
```

...you can select by label text:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("airports"))); 
select.selectByVisibleText("Portland");
```

...or by value:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("airports"))); 
select.selectByValue("pdx");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.expedia.co.in/Flights");
WebElement textbox=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='flight-origin']"));
textbox.clear();
textbox.sendKeys("LAS");
Thread.sleep(4000);
List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='typeahead-list']"));
int count=allOptions.size();
System.out.println("No of autosuggestions"+count);
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
String text=allOptions.get(i).getText();
System.out.println(text);
}
textbox.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
textbox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
}
```

Comment: is ur  question related to data driven ?

Answer (score -2):

Hi please find the solution to above problem

```
package com.daythree;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ExpediaProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\workspace\\...\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.navigate().to("https://www.expedia.co.in/Flights");
        driver.findElement(By.id("flight-origin")).click();
        // Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("flight-origin")).sendKeys("las");

        // wait for the suggestions to appear

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@role='listbox']/div/li/a/div/div"))));

        List<WebElement> suggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='listbox']/div/li/a/div/div"));
        System.out.println("Size of the suggestions is : " + suggestions);

        String val = "Las Vegas, NV, US";
        for(int i=0;i<suggestions.size();i++){
            // this will print all the suggestions
            System.out.println("value is : " + suggestions.get(i).getText());

            // now logic to select the option
            if(suggestions.get(i).getText().contains(val)){
                suggestions.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You've got `Thread.sleep()` and implicit waits both of which are bad practices. You've also mixed implicit and explicit waits which is warned against in the official docs.

Comment: @ jeffC i used Thread.sleep() just to make sure OS understands whats going in script line byline evne if u remove Thread.sleep() it is not going to hamper the way of execution,,also can u provide me official link where it says  mixed implicit and explicit waits cannot be used

Comment: @rajNishKuMar- URL 
URL: https://www.cheapoair.com/deals/business-class-airfares . if u eneter the origin as 'LAS', the list is autopopulated , but u cannot inspect element to select the xpath for the Autopopulated list. Currently Close icon appears in the bottom and i click on that and las get populated. But I have to select the Aiirport code from the List.

Comment: @rajNishKuMar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474296/clarification-on-the-cause-of-mixing-implicit-and-explicit-waits-of-selenium-doc

Comment: public void FlightInput(){
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Workspace\\src\\test\\Resources\\com\\cucumber\\google\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.cheapoair.com/deals/business-class-airfares");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='signupClose icon ic-cancel-fill']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("ember530")).clear();

Comment: @rajNishKuMar http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits. `WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. `