# java.lang.NullPointerException in ExpectedConditions using Selenium through WebDriverManager

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java, expected-condition

Following line gives error:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")));
```

Code is as below:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://test.salesforce.com/");
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("");
driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'home-accounts')]")));**
```

Also, I have observed:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'home-accounts')]")));
```

is working fine.

How to handle it?

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed(RemoteWebElement.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:248)
    at TestClass.NewTest.TC_DealDetails_0(NewTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have `implicitlyWait` declared in your WebDriver. When you have `implicitlyWait` configured, you don't need to use explicit waits such as `wait.until`.

When you mix implicit and explicit waits like in this example, you may get some unexpected results, some explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474296/clarification-of-the-cause-of-mixing-implicit-and-explicit-waits-of-selenium-doc).

You can try to remove `wait.until` statements and see if your code still works.

Answer (score 0):

the difference is that ***visibilityOfElementLocated()*** checks some element styles like width and height, while ***presenceOfElementLocated()*** should check only existence. 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-

Is your element really *visible* on the page?

---

Also it would be nice to see the stacktrace, as .until() should raise TimeoutException if element is not found, not Null Pointer

https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: Element is visible on the webpage. Stack trace is as follows

Comment: what version of the selenium are you using please? There was an issue with this indeed that was fixed a year ago https://github.com/clarmso/selenium/commit/41474ee1a4718aeb0d3ab53f5ad5d4e7645105ea
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5809

Comment: and yeah, fix should be available since selenium-3.141.0

Answer (score 0):

### WebDriverManager

[WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) allows to automate the management of the binary drivers (e.g. chromedriver, geckodriver, etc.) required by [Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491). By adding the following line:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

[WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/README.md) does the following tasks for you:

- It checks the version of the browser installed in your machine (i.e. Chrome).
- It checks the version of the driver (i.e. chromedriver). If unknown, it uses the latest version of the driver.
- It downloads the WebDriver binary if it is not present on the WebDriverManager cache (`~/.m2/repository/webdriver` by default).
- It exports the proper WebDriver Java environment variables required by Selenium.

Moving forward instead of creating the `driver` from the **ChromeDriver** *Class* you need to use the **WebDriver** *interface*. So you need to replace:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

with:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```