# Selenium is it ok to use implicit waits alongside explicit waits? (Using Page Object Model)

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

I have written a Selenium Java Framework that uses both implicit waits and explicit waits.

I am using Page Object Model so all of the elements are declared at the top of the page class as shown here:

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "firstname")
public WebElement firstname;
```

The elements are instantiated using Page Factory as shown here:

```
public BasePage() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

When I first move to a new webpage I use an explicit wait to check that one of the elements on the page is there. To do this, I temporarily set the implicit wait to 0 (so it doesn't clash) then use a WebDriverWait to wait for the element as shown here:

```
    CommonUtil.waitForElementVisible(save,properties.getProperty("TimeOutSeconds"));
```

//This is the actual method in CommonUtil:

```
public static void waitForElementVisible(WebElement element, String timeoutSecondsAsString) {

    //Temporarily set the default(implicit) timeout to 0 seconds otherwise it will override the timeout specified in this method
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Integer.parseInt(timeoutSecondsAsString));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

    //Set the default (implicit) timeout back to the default
    long timeout = Long.valueOf(properties.getProperty("TimeOutSeconds"));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Once I have done the explicit wait for one of the objects, I use the implicit wait for the rest of the objects, so that I can sendKeys, click etc really easily without having to use any wait commands as shown here:

```
    firstname.sendKeys("firstName");
    lastname.sendKeys("Surname");
    checkout.click();
```

I have been told that I should not be using implicit waits alongside explicit waits. Is this correct? It seems fine to me and is working perfectly. I would have to write a lot more code if I have to write an explicit wait before clicking or sendingkeys to every field and defeats the object of the Page Object Model being so simple and neat.

Comment: U actually are not mixing implicit and explicit wait in the same call. When u are using visibility expectedcondition u are setting implicit to 0. If this was not set to 0 you will get unpredictable wait times - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474296/clarification-of-the-cause-of-mixing-implicit-and-explicit-waits-of-selenium-doc. You should not have problems if use waits this way

Comment: Thats what I thought!