# What will the output of using implicit and explicit wait together using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, implicitwait

How Selenium will behave for following conditions:

WHEN ELEMENT IS FOUND AT 6 SEC
--Implicit wait = 5sec Explicit wait= 10 sec

WHEN ELEMENT IS FOUND AT 6 SEC
--Implicit wait = 10sec Explicit wait= 5 sec

WHEN ELEMENT IS FOUND AT 11 SEC
--Implicit wait = 10sec Explicit wait= 10 sec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clarification of the cause of mixing Implicit and Explicit waits in Selenium doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474296/clarification-of-the-cause-of-mixing-implicit-and-explicit-waits-in-selenium-doc)

Answer (score 0):

To clear off all the speculations, as per the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [official docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#implicit-wait):

> > Warning: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.