# How to declare WebDriver timeouts and how to manage their priority?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

For the webdriver I set up at some early point of code

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

then later I declare something like that

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(bla bla
```

or

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(bla bla
```

and it seems it doesn't have effect I expect because it waits longer then 5 sec

What are the rulles for those timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** mix implicit waits with explicit waits.
That means if you defined non-default value for `implicitlyWait` you should not use `WebDriverWait` in that driver session.
See the [official recommendations](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#:%7E:text=Warning%3A%20Do%20not%20mix%20implicit,to%20occur%20after%2020%20seconds.) saying `Warning: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds`.
Normally we always use `WebDriverWait` explicit waits only leaving `implicitlyWait` set to it default value `0`.
You can see more explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474296/clarification-of-the-cause-of-mixing-implicit-and-explicit-waits-in-selenium-doc) and in more similar discussions.