# Selenium findElement-s not adhering to explicit wait but to implicit wait only

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, jvm

I want to make the following junit + selenium-jvm-test fail in 3s using the explicit wait instead of 20s (the implicit wait) without fiddling with the implicit wait setting. How can I achieve this?

Unfortunately `findElements` waits the full 20s, too, as well as all `ExpectedConditions` relying on `findElements` and `findElement`. Do you have any idea?

```
    @Test
    void isGoogleOpen() {
        // this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.of(20, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)); happens in @BeforeEach
        this.driver.get("https://google.de");

        String wrongClassName = "lnXdpdIAMERROR";

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3));
        wait.until(d -> d.findElement(By.className(wrongClassName)).isDisplayed());
    }
```

Comment: The Selenium docs specifically state not to mix implicit and explicit waits (like WebDriverWait). Don't do this. Also, the Selenium authors have stated repeatedly that we shouldn't use implicit waits at all and that explicit waits are the correct way to wait using Selenium.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks for your reply. As I'm a person that wants to know the Why behind such statements, I got inspired and found this interesting thread that explains by example what exactly happens in cases like mine.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474296/clarification-of-the-cause-of-mixing-implicit-and-explicit-waits-in-selenium-doc

For anyone wondering like me.

Comment: Sorry for double post, but that one is too great not to link it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067495/1203693

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rewrite this code so that if the element does not appear within 3 seconds, the exception you need will be thrown. Here's a code that might help:

```
@Test
void isGoogleOpen() {
    this.driver.get("https://google.de");

    String wrongClassName = "lnXdpdIAMERROR";

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver,Duration.ofSeconds(3));
    try {  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className(wrongClassName)));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // Case processing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately this doesn't do it, because `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` relies on findElement which has to be executed at least once using the full implicit wait defined above. If you are interested, check out the post I linked in my comment under the original post. That describes it very well.